# Ubuntu 17.10 won't connect to mobile hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 alongside Windows 8.

My wifi router isn't working so I am stuck with using a hotspot from Samsung Galaxy S Duos. Ubuntu recognizes the hotspot network but when I try to connect it, it attempts to connect and without any message or error stops trying.

I tried several times, changed passwords, changed security types but no success. For a brief moment, it did connect but it did not work and quickly disconnected again.

What should I do?

**Note:** Also the Broadcom driver is not present for some reason. Is there a way to download it from Windows and install on Ubuntu. I think that might resolve my problem.

Comment: Why do you think you need the broadcom driver?  Use USB tethering to the phone and edit the question to include results for the [wireless script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665)

Answer (score 0):

You should plug your device to an Internet cable and run terminal and run this very simple command :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then after completing that process, you'll find out Broadcom wireless driver in the "Additional Drivers" tab of the "Software & Updates" app.
install it and you'll be able to connect to any wireless connection you want. 
I had a problem like yours and fixed it with this simple way, hope it works for you too!